# Read/Write Locks on Methods of Injected Class

Tags: java, sql, groovy, dependency-injection, locking

I'm currently working on a RESTful web service that is reading and writing from two different databases. The problem I am running into is handling cases where my service gets called and then a second call is received before the first finishes writing. The service reads a date field in the database to determine if it needs to INSERT or UPDATE and then writes to that field in the chosen operation. If the second call is made before the first is finished, the date field will not have been written to, so I end up with two INSERTS rather than an INSERT and an UPDATE.

I tried using the concurrency API available in java as well as in groovy but so far I have not been able to get it to work. The RESTful service looks up a fresh copy of the model class each time it is called. The model class then gets a new instance of the groovy object via dependency injection. As a result, I can't put an instance of the Lock in either place since each call of the RESTful service will be working on a new instance of the model and the groovy.

Can anyone suggest a better way to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**

Here is some pseudo code for the service

> 1. Lookup model data by id from table A of database 1.
> 2. Lookup the most recent entry in table B of database 2 where the id matches a key stored in the model (dw_id).
> 3. Compare the 'start date' column of the results to the current datetime.
>
> **If** the 'day' of the start_date == the current day **then**:
>
> 4a. execute an UPDATE query on table B of database 2 using data
>   obtained from the model.
>
> **Else**:
>
> 5a. Execute an UPDATE query on table B of database 2, replacing the
>   value of the end_date column with yesterday's date where id == dw_id.
>
> 5b. Execute an INSERT on table B of database 2, using data from the
>   model, setting start_date to today's date and the end_date to a
>   constant future date.
>
> 5c. Execute an UPDATE on table A of database 1, replacing the dw_id of
>   the model with the auto-generated id of the entry created by the
>   INSERT from 5b.

**UPDATE 2**

I ended up implementing something similar to the solution proposed by [jan-willem-gmelig-meyling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2104280/jan-willem-gmelig-meyling). I found a good example of an implementation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27806218/32453 that I was able to adapt to suit my needs.

Comment: Typically locking is something that the database should handle, and are really good at. You should try to do your operation with SQL, ie a case statement where it checks  the value of the select to determine if the query should be an insert or an update. The DB you are using will handle the concurrency cases for you.

Comment: How about putting a Stored procedure to be called to do all the stuff. Then handle the locking in the stored proc.

Comment: Could you provide an example of using a case statement to modify the type of query in SQL?

Comment: One other complication with doing a conditional query. There is an additional UPDATE statement that only gets run during the INSERT case. The database does change tracking by creating duplicates with updated start/end dates every 24 hours (hence the need to switch between an insert or update). So If I am doing an insert, I need to update the start/end date of the current most recent record before inserting the new record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java you can do this by synchronising on a lock object. This however only works if you acquire this lock before starting a database transaction. Otherwise, the two parallel threads will start a database transaction simultaneously and live in isolated database versions. So what you roughly get:

```
private final static Object lock = new Object();

public void myResource() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        // begin tx, do work, end tx.
        // Other callee won't get here before first callee is finished
    }
}
```

This however does break all server stateless conventions. It is much better to actually lock the database table in your transaction. This prevents another connection from simultaneously reading from and writing to the same table. You can investigate which locking mechanisms are supported for your database (or ORM library, if using any). A technique such as JTA can be utilised to share database transactions between servers, services, or multiple databases.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on what you mean when you say this breaks stateless server conventions? Are there potential side effects or 'gotchas' I need to look out for if I go with this solution?

Comment: Yes, because you synchronise on a static lock object, that lock only resists within the same JVM. So if you start load balancing between two servers running two separate JVMs, this mechanism will not work anymore. You then need to develop something to lock / synchronise across multiple nodes.

Comment: Ok, good to know. At this point, our application does not have to deal with that. If the situation changes in the future, do you know of any good resources that demonstrate how to implement locking properly at the database level?

Comment: See for example how to do this in JPA: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Locking#JPA_2.0_Locking . Or the documentation of Narayana which an implementation for JTA, which allows for multi-node or multi-database locks and transactions: http://narayana.io//docs/project/index.html