# Multithreading problem when trying select and insert in single method

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

friends!
I'm working with Play+Java+Ebean.
I've got a problem with parallel threads when trying to select and insert values to DB in one method.
At first, I check the existence of a device in my DB(PostgreSQL) by id.
If I haven't found the device by id, I try to insert it to DB.
Then I return Device object.
All works fine except the situation when two http-requests asynchronously try to send to me the same device ids. Firstly both of them select a value from DB and return nothing. Then one inserts values and the second fails because of io.eBean.DuplicateKeyException.

I've tried to synchronize method. It works but I don't like this solution. If I do this many requests will be put in a queue. I want to stay in parallel but synchronize only if I have two or more requests with the same id.
Another way to solve the problem is to write a query with INSERT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...) RETURNING. But it isn't an object style and there is hardcoding for several operations of the same type.

```
public CompletionStage<Device> getDevice(String deviceID, String ipAddress) {
return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
SecurityRepository.findDeviceByDeviceID(deviceID))       
    .thenApplyAsync(curDevice -> curDevice
        .orElseGet(() -> {
            List<Device> devices = 
            SecurityRepository.listDevicesByIpAddress(ipAddress);
            if(devices.size() >= 10) {
                 for(Device device : devices)
        device.delete();
    }
    Device newDevice = new Device();
    newDevice.setDeviceID(deviceID);
    newDevice.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    newDevice.save(); //here is the problem
    return newDevice;
      })
);
```

}

I want to synchronize this method if and only if deviceID is the same.
Have you any suggestions to this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: If it does no harm then let the second thread fail and just log a message in case of exception so that you know such a scenario occurred. Synchronization will make other threads to wait which may not look good performance wise. Also, you can move the check for id existence condition at the query level.

Comment: There will be a problem because I need to return an object, created or taken from DB. If I permit the second thread to fail then the method doesn't return anything. Checking existence on the query level is a good idea. But can I do it with ORM (EBean in my case)? Because I don't want to hardcode queries.

Comment: Well, you can always return error response from second thread in case it fails. If deviceID is an object then you can use lock to block any other thread which might be using the same deviceID. Check the following SO question, there are many suggestions for your usecase:    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282166/java-synchronizing-on-primitives